# Use AS3 to turn on/off a graphic's visibility

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found other threads/questions that were similar but didn't quite provide the answer I need.

This should be incredibly simple, but I'm not very versed in AS3 yet so I'm stuck.

I have a movie clip on the stage whose alpha is set at 0. I want to make it so that when I press a certain key on my keyboard the alpha for that movie clip is set to 1 (100%). I already have several other keys coded in AS3 to do other actions (jump to certain frames in the timeline, move certain objects up, down, left and right, etc). So I added this code:

```
if (e.keyCode == 77){
    graphic_object.alpha == 1;
}
```

"graphic_object" is the instance name for the movie clip I want to show.

However, when I press the "M" key (77), nothing shows up. The movie clip apparently remains at 0.

So what's the incredibly simple resolution to this that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` => comparison

`=` => setter

```
graphics_object.alpha = 1;
```

Comment: See, I knew it was simple. Thanks!